# how to get subject, from and body from mailman rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman-gem

i have code like this

```
Mailman::Application.run do
  to 'email@local.com' do
     ## how to get subject, from and body in here
  end
end
```

how to get subject, from and body from email in rails?

Comment: You do not have your mailman application configured to poll an account for any incoming emails. Is that what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Use mail gem https://github.com/mikel/mail/

```
Mailman::Application.run do
  default do
    mail = Mail.new(message)
    from = message.from.first
    content = mail.parts[1].body.decoded
    subject = message.subject
    //your other code

  end
end
```